# Is that possible to use apache arrow integration with relation database?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, apache-arrow

Apache Arrow is an in-memory columnar data structure and relational database is a line data structure. If we still use MySQL to store these in-memory data, the only way is to save the arrow file in the relational database or can I have any other choice?

Comment: Both are tabular data structures.  You will need to convert from one to the other.  If the columns of your arrow table match the columns in a MySQL table it should be possible to convert it.  I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for your response.My point is,is that possible to use apache-arrow with mysql together as the application database ? At same time,building a quene to sync data between arrow  and mysql to guarantee data consistency.